# Can C# use #if to compare a value with less than or greater than?

Tags: c#, .net, preprocessor-directive

Is there any way in C# to use the #if directive to compare a value with a less than or greater than operator?

Example:

```
#if GAME_SDK_VERSION < 500

#else

#endif
```

*EDIT* I see the duplicate question link but it does not clearly address my simple question of using greater than or less than symbols. I think this question is valuable enough, along with the answer given to stand on it's own.

Comment: No, you can only define compile time symbols.  They have no inherent value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compile time checking of conditional compilation symbols in C# (see example)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806738/compile-time-checking-of-conditional-compilation-symbols-in-c-sharp-see-example), also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842590/how-do-i-set-a-conditional-compile-variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't. Quote from [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx):

> Unlike C and C++, you cannot assign a numeric value to a symbol; the #if statement in C# is Boolean and only tests whether the symbol has been defined or not.

As a workaround I have used symbols that mean "greater than or equal to X", for instance for version 3 I would define something to the effect of `VER_GTE_1`, `VER_GTE_2` and `VER_GTE_3`. The other alternative is to only define the current version and use a long list of `||` in the `#if`.

This does quickly get infeasible for very large numbers. Perhaps the best way is to avoid preprocessor directives as much as possible - I think C# has better opportunities for this than C/C++.

Comment: Thanks. Right now I am using #if with || for Unity versions, which gets large, especially with API changes between versions like 4.2 and 4.3, etc.